# How to register a new domain name on a windows based domain controller?

Tags: windows, domain, subdomain

Is there an easy and quick way I can create a new subdomain on a windows based domain controller. My primary domain controller is also my primary DNS server on my network.

I want to create a subdomain and have its ip directed to that of my IIS server.

Thanks in advance...

Sorry if my terminology is somewhat lacking...

My domain is

companyName.com

What I want to do is create auditingResults.companyName.com... and have it route to 192.168.1.3 for example..... where on 1.3 I will have an IIS server presetup.

Please feel free to leave comments to correct my terminology if required....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about a DNS domain (and ***not*** a new AD domain), then is as simple as going to your DNS server's management console and defining a new zone; if you make it AD-integrated, it will automatically get replicated to all of your DC/DNS servers.

So, if your main domain is `domain.local`, just go to DNS, create a new zone called `subdomain.domain.local` and then define any record you want inside it, such as `www.subdomain.domain.local`.

If you also want `subdomain.domain.local` to point to a given IP address, the solution is creating a blank A record in the new zone.

---

### Edit:

Looks like you don't want a subdomain, but only a hostname inside the domain you already have.

It's even simpler then: go to your DNS server's management console and create an **A** record, give it the name you like and assign it the IP address you want it to point to.

Comment: Thank you very much.... sounds like you understand what I need to do, could you please explain where I need to click to get there?

Comment: Which version of Windows Server is your DC running?

Comment: I created a host entry, was very easy - clicked DNS in administrative tools... from there was self explanatory (Windows Server 2008)